# Getting ERROR ERROR [object Object] but only on ios. Works fine on computer

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari

I have a site deployed and was working fine last I checked(last couple days), but today, using the site in chrome ios or safari ios doesn't work. On the chrome I used chrome://inspect but all it says is

```
ERROR ERROR [object Object]
```

You can try this out for yourself if you want:
https://thehowlingwolfe.web.app/admin

It should display a table and then after a bit it should load the data in that table. Thanks for your help and let me know if there are any sections of code you would like me to post.

Comment: You seem to be fetching something from localhost, which is a problem if you are not on your computer

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I'm dumb. I was using ng build instead of ng build --prod which left my localhost in there. How were you able to see that I was fetching from a localhost?

Comment: I looked at the console window in Chrome

Comment: for the admin page? weird, I didn't see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@knosmos Was right. I was using 'ng build' instead of 'ng build --prod' which left my localhost in production.